# How to insert automatically value in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need a backup script but the executed program after executing asks Y or N for continuing.
How to write a script to automatically insert Y.

for example the program acts like this
c:\tool\backup.exe -b
Continue Y, N?

now I would need that I create a bat script, but how to insert Y automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the program doesn't have a switch to turn off interactive behavior, you can use

```
echo Y | someprogram.exe
```

which will look to someprogram as if the user would have entered `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

A commandline program usually has a switch for automatically answering the questions with Y (this is usually -Y) but if your program doesn't have a switch like that, I don't think you can easily accomplish what you want to do...

Edit: Johannes is right, his suggestion should be an easy way to accomplish this... why haven't I thought about this ;-)

Anyways, If that doesn't work you can always try to accomplish this externally with something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml).